# How to select multiple elements in a string separated by ";" and "," in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split, spyder

Example:

1st line of the dataframe: `name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3`

2nd line of the dataframe: `name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c`

I would like to select only the countries of each line of the dataframe and then create a new column in the same dataframe:

`country 1, country 2, country 3`

`country a, country b, country c`

I tried this but I could only get the last country of the last school per line

`df["countries"] = df["school_info"].apply(lambda x: str(x).split(",")[-1].strip())`

output:

`country 3`

`country c`

Thank you!

Comment: Can you include the input dataframe and example of output datafrme?

Comment: The file has not been read in correctly. Include the line where you read the data in.

Comment: How many columns do you have? Are all the countries in the column school_info?

Comment: Try `df["school_info"].str.split(r"[,;]\s", expand=True).iloc[:,2::3]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your lines are in one column named school_info:

```
df["school_info"].apply(lambda r: ', '.join([c.split(",")[-1].strip() for c in r.split(";")]))
```

Input:

```
data = [["name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3"],
        ["name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c"]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['school_info'])
```

Output:

```
0    country 1, country 2, country 3
1    country a, country b, country c
Name: school_info, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you! That was exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 0):

OK - now I've understood what your requirement

1. build a temporary `list` of `tuples` which you want to become rows
2. use `explode()` to expand list into rows
3. pick out values in `tuple` on each row to form columns.  For purpose of example I've picked out all components and left original encoded string in place

```
data = """name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3
name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c"""

df = pd.DataFrame({"school_info":data.split("\n")})
# df["data_tuple"] = df["school_info"].apply(lambda s: [tuple(t.split(",")) for t in s.split(";")])
df = df.assign(data_tuple=lambda dfa: dfa["school_info"].apply(
    # build a list of tuples - delimiter is ";" each tuple contains (name,age,country)
    lambda s: [tuple(t.split(",")) for t in s.split(";")]))\
    # explode the list and pick out each of the elements of resultant tuple
    .explode("data_tuple").assign(
        name=lambda dfa: dfa["data_tuple"].apply(lambda t: t[0]),
        age=lambda dfa: dfa["data_tuple"].apply(lambda t: t[1]),
        country=lambda dfa: dfa["data_tuple"].apply(lambda t: t[2]),
).drop("data_tuple", axis=1) # this was a temporary contruct drop it

print(df.to_string(index=False))
```

**output**

```
                                                                  school_info     name     age     country
 name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3   name 1   age 1   country 1
 name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3   name 2   age 2   country 2
 name 1, age 1, country 1; name 2, age 2, country 2; name 3, age 3, country 3   name 3   age 3   country 3
 name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c   name a   age a   country a
 name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c   name b   age b   country b
 name a, age a, country a; name b, age b, country b; name c, age c, country c   name c   age c   country c
```